# Experiencing "404-unknown error" when attempting to lis team channel tabs with Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

For a given team I want to choose a specific channel and list the tabs for the channel.

Using x to censor IDs:

I am able to use the following `HTTP GET` call to view the group:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/193cexxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And the following allows me to view the specific channel:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/193cexxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
/team/channels/19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype/
```

The result looks like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#groups('193cee12-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a8022fe6754c')/team/channels/$entity",
    "id": "19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype",
    "displayName": "General",
    "description": "Test ",
    "email": "",
    "webUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/19%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40thread.skype/General?groupId=193cee12-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a8022fe6754c&tenantId=d02b4c26-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0e19a90257d6"
}
```

The error occurs when I try to access any properties of the channel:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/193cexxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
/team/channels/19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype/tabs
```

The error looks like this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1b1040df-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-04c7952674ba",
            "date": "2019-11-04T11:xx:xx"
        }
    }
}
```

I am a group Owner.

There is no error message so it's hard to figure out what goes wrong. Has anybody else experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the information about the channels, you need to use the `teams` segment instead of the `groups` segment.

```
      \/ -- 'teams' here, not 'groups'
/v1.0/teams/193cexxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/channels/19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@thread.skype/tabs
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-list?view=graph-rest-1.0